# gcc can't find `FT_Error_String` when trying to compile

Tags: c, gcc, freetype, freetype2

I am trying to compile an application that uses *freetype2*, I downloaded and compiled the latest version of *freetype2* from an official site.
I compile the program using this command:

```
gcc ttf2sfn.c -I/home/emilia/os/freetype-2.10.1/include -L/home/emilia/os/freetype-2.10.1/objs -lfreetype
```

However, the linker cannot find the `FT_Error_String' character.
It prints this error message:

```
/tmp/cc6FGxyc.o: In function `main':
ttf2sfn.c:(.text+0x25aa): undefined reference to `FT_Error_String'
ttf2sfn.c:(.text+0x352c): undefined reference to `FT_Error_String'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is this happening?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to actually exist. I use my own function, called `ftstrerror`, to do something equivalent:

```
static const char *ftstrerror(FT_Error error)
{
#undef FTERRORS_H_
#define FT_ERRORDEF(error_code, value, string) case error_code: return string;
#define FT_ERROR_START_LIST switch(error) {
#define FT_ERROR_END_LIST default: return "Unknown error"; }
#include FT_ERRORS_H
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tested with FreeType 2.10.3.]  You must have done something wrong.  `FT_Error_String` is *always* defined.  However, only if the library has been configured (at build time) with macro `FT_CONFIG_OPTION_ERROR_STRINGS` set, it returns non-NULL values.  Since the default is off, you have to explicitly enable this feature in file `include/freetype/config/ftoption.h`.